# Older versions of IE pushes DIV further away

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position, html

I have a DIV which is displayed on top of images of items that are for sale on a portfolio website. This works fine in standard browsers, but when it comes to older browsers (the dreaded IE) for some reason the DIV is pushed to the right.

Any help would be appreciated

This is the code for the for-sale banner;

```
 .post .forsale {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  display: none;
  background-image: url(images/fs.png); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 

}
```

This is the code for `.post`

```
.post {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 380px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 62px;
  background:  #e0e0e0;
  vertical-align: top;
    *display: inline; 
    zoom: 1; 
}
```

Comment: **Which** versions of IE????

Comment: it works in "to-standard ones"(from 8) but not below 7... (compatibility view)

Comment: Difficult to debug without a link to your page or a [demo of the problem](http://jsbin.com/). As a shot in the dark, try specifying `left: 0` (or whatever value) on `.post .forsale`.

Comment: using `left: 0` or any value makes it so I only have 1 instance of that banner. Bare with me and I'll get a demo up :)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/adaCEWe/1/watch?html,css,output